# Symfony/Doctrine - Keeping the database up to date with an external data source

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on an application that heavily depends on data from an external API. I need to store it in a database to perform some searches etc. The data changes quite often and has to be "synchronized" daily. So I'm looking for an efficient way to pull down the new data from the API and update the database with the new, updated and deleted entities.

However I've only come across suggestions about querying for differences for each entity to determine whether to do an update or an insert, which seems very inefficient to me. Or truncating all the data and just make inserts. But are there any existing (more efficient) tools, techniques or strategies for this, or is it the way to go?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a hash for each item, and compare it during next import. You need two things for each row:

1. An unique ID
2. A hash of the data that can change

For example, if you recieve an entry like this:

```
{
   "id": 42,
   "title": "something",
   "description": "the description of this item"
}
```

You generate a hash `sha1($row['title'].'|'.$row['description'])` and during the next import all you have to do is to compare the old hash to the new one. You will have to follow these rules:

1. If the ID of the row does not exist in your database: INSERT
2. If the ID of the row exists in your database AND the hash from your database is not the same than the one you generate from the row: UPDATE
3. If an ID from your database is missing from the fresh data: DELETE

Ps: you can replace the hash with a date IF the external API give you access to the last modified time for each row.

Comment: Interesting solution, I'll look into it! Thanks

Comment: @JohanPalmfjord Have you solved your problem? If yes could you share it with us? I have the same dilemma already.

Comment: @nicram I ended up writing a diff checker that did basically what this answer suggests. The dataset was small enough to keep in memory so I was able to query everything in one select and then do the diff checks between the 2 different lists. It wasn't super-fast but not slow enough for it to be a problem in this case. Unfortunately I don't have the code anymore so it's hard to share the details, sorry.